# Close HttpWebRequest to free up resources

Tags: c#, stream, httpwebrequest

I am creating HTTP WebRequests in c# to navigate a website. I create the request, get a response and read it into a StreamReader. I then use the same request variable to create a new request and get a new response...

Below is my code:

```
HttpWebRequest request;
WebResponse response;
Stream responseStream;
StreamReader reader;
string responseFromServer;

request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.firstRequest.com");

//set cookies and headers here... 

response = request.GetResponse();

responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();


//second request using the same variables
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.secondRequest.com");
response = request.GetResponse();

responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

I know I have to close the response, stream and streamreader to free up resources. 
Do I have to do it in between each request or just at the end of everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alltough @spender has a point when he's saying you should be using `using` directives, I don't think that his answer answers your question or is particularly helpful.

When thinking about problems like this, think about the fundamentals of C# and objects that implement `IDisposable`. Classes that do so make use of unmanaged resources that need to be freed when the class is no longer used. This happens either at the end of the `using`-block or when `Dispose` is called.

After a call to `Dispose` however, the object should not be used anymore. This is a fundamental difference to `Close`. Using `Close` the response frees resources and the same object can be reused by another request.
[MSDN for Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Now let's consider what would happen if you simply overrode the response variable. classes are a reference type in C#, the variable would now reference a new object and the old response object would vanish in nirvana, waiting to be eventually collected by the GC without `Dispose` being invoked. Certainly not what you want.

So if you want to reuse variables, make sure you use `Close`

Comment: and which ones do I have to close? response, streamreader and reader? not request - right? And does it hurt to close the same resource twice? I called close in a loop and then when it breaks out of the loop I want to call close again to be positive. Is that OK?

Comment: The request doesn't implement `IDisposable` so there's nothing to close there. Everything else should be closed correctly. Of course you can reuse the variable in the loop if you use `Close` each time. Dependent on how often the loop runs, you might want to consider a more efficient alternative. Just make sure that Close is called before the variable is overridden or not used anymore. This can usually easily be achieved by good loop-design.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to clean up after yourself every time. Just make use of the IDisposable features that you're ignoring:

So, instead, you could

```
using(response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using(responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using(reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

or more concisely:

```
using(response = request.GetResponse())
using(responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
using(reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
{
    responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

...now you don't need to worry about calling `Close`. The IDisposable implementation takes care of it for you (when the `using` block ends).

Comment: So then where do I out code that needs to go in between your using statements?

Comment: Sure. You say using, using, using and then your code block. Could I reference the response in the code block - or is it already closed. I'm not understanding the way you wrote the code. Thanks

Comment: So I altered my code so that hopefully it's a little more self explanatory. Yes, you can reference the response within its using block. After the end of the block, `Dispose` will be called automatically on the "used" item. Calling Dispose and Close are equivalent, so this fulfills your requirements. Once dispose is called, it's often unsafe to continue using the disposed item. Assigning a new response to the variable is safe though.